# GetSecurityDescriptor parameters

Tags: excel, vba, file-locking

I was looking for a function to find the username locking a file.

I found this one which works fine:

```
Function GetUsername(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As String

'On Error Resume Next
Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object

Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)

GetUsername = secDesc.Owner

End Function
```

I wanted to change

```
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
```

For

```
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fullFileName, 1, 1)
```

I made the required change at the function declaration, even tried without any function but couldn't make the method work with a unique variable containing the full path, forcing me to split it for a reason I don't understand.

Here are the full function (well translated I hope)

```
Function GetUsername(fileDir As String, fileName As String) As 
String 'case 1
'Function GetUsername(fullFileName As String) As String 'case 2

Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object

Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1) 'case 1
'Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(fullFileName, 1, 1) 'case 2

GetUsername = secDesc.Owner

End Function


Function IsOpen(file As String) As Boolean

Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

On Error Resume Next
filenum = FreeFile()

Open file For Input Lock Read As #filenum
Close filenum
errnum = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case errnum
    Case 0
        IsOpen = False
    Case 70
        IsOpen = True
    Case Else
        Error errnum
End Select
End Function


Function CheckFile(file As String) As Boolean

'existence test
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fs.fileexists(file) = True Then 'the file exists
    If IsOpen(file) = True Then 'the file is open
        MsgBox "file opened" & Chr(10) & "By : " & GetUsername("R\", "TEST.xlsx") 'case 1 : works
        'MsgBox "file opened" & Chr(10) & "By : " & GetUsername(file) 'case 2 : don't works
    Else
        MsgBox "closed file"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "ERROR: The file does not exists"
End If

End Function


Private Sub TestOpen()

Dim ftest As String

ftest = "R:\TEST.xlsx"

CheckFile (ftest)

End Sub
```

Comment: We would need to see the updated function and how you are calling it.  Also, have you inspected fullFileName to make sure it contains a valid path?

Comment: I indeed have inspected fullFileName, everything is fine with this variable as well as the path contained in it.

Comment: `forcing me to split it for a reason I don't understand` - in which way does it not work? Does it work with `secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(CStr(fullFileName), 1, 1)` or `secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(ByVal fullFileName, 1, 1)`?

Comment: Unfornately neither worked : 
    `secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(CStr(fullFileName), 1, 1)` : Type incompatibility

    `secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(ByVal fullFileName, 1, 1)` : object required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadssecurityutility-getsecuritydescriptor) for `GetSecurityDescriptor` seems rather emphatic that the first parameter must be a variant.

> A VARIANT string that contains the path of the object to retrieve the
> security descriptor for.

I tried your revised code and sure enough it did not work.  However, after making one small change to force the parameter to variant the code worked fine.

```
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(CVar(fullFileName), 1, 1)
```

So what is the difference between case 1 and case 2 from your question?  I don't know.  But it seems the result of concatenating 2 strings is a variant which is why case 1 worked.

Comment: The first case uses two string parameters and concatenate them.
The second, only one parameter as string (does not work because of the wrong type).
So you answered to my question wich was "how to make case 2 work ?"